# Calling Python function with Javascript in MAMP

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, apache, permissions

What I am trying to do is take a Python file (for now I have a simple test file that outputs some generic text) and have Javascript run it when a button is clicked. I want the output from the Python script to be logged to the console by Javascript.

I have set the httpd.conf file to ExecCGI and had it run Python files as .cgi files (see http://www.editrocket.com/articles/python_apache_windows.html). I have also changed the permissions for the MAMP folder and all of its contents read/write for everybody just in case. However, when I try and make an Ajax call on my file I get a 500 internal server error. When I go to localhost:8888/cgi-bin I get a Forbidden Access error. For reference, my Javascript is in `MAMP/htdocs/WebScraper/` and my Python file is in `MAMP/cgi-bin/`.

Here is my Python file code:

```
print("Content-type: text/html")
print()
print("<p>Hello World</p>")
```

and here is my Javascript file code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/cgi-bin/cgi_test.py",
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I know it is hitting the file because I am getting a 500 error instead of a 404, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make it work. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: You have to invoke the python interpreter. If you're on unix/mac, type which python and then put the path at the top of your file with #!<path to interpreter> its usually /usr/bin/python. Also make sure the file has executable permissions.

Comment: Also, what do your logs say?

Comment: Alright I put the interpreter path at the top and also ran `chmod -R 777 /Applications/MAMP/` just to make sure everything was covered but still no luck. Here is my log, `[Thu Aug 06 12:55:31 2015] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] malformed header from script. Bad header=(): cgi_test.py, referer: http://localhost:8888/Web%20Scraper/` and my Python file:     `#!/usr/bin/python
    print("Content-type: text/html")
    print()
    print("<html>")
    print("<body>")
    print("<p>Hello World</p>")
    print("</body>")
    print("</html>")`

Comment: Also sorry about the formatting, I can't find any way to make a code block in a comment

Comment: Actually just figured it out, but thanks for your help anyways since I needed to do those things too!

Answer (score 1):

Alright I figured it out, I needed to add a `\n` inside `print("Content-type: text/html")` to make it `print("Content-type: text/html\n")`. This is to separate the headers from the rest of the content or else the program doesn't know which is which.